# List of open (uncommitted transactions) in DB2 LUW

Tags: db2, transaction, db2-luw

How can I get list of open (uncommitted transactions) in DB2 LUW?

Or just the oldest transaction id?

Basically, I need to get the first change of the oldest open transaction. I found APPL_ID_OLDEST_XACT in SYSIBMADM.SNAPDB view, but it tells me only the application id and I could figure out how to get to the actual LSN/LRI.

I was suggested to use db2pd -transactions, but I can only run it from server side.
Is there a solution that I can run from client side?

Comment: It's not clear what you want: transaction ID or LSN? These are different things.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to learn with this information?

Comment: Basically i need the oldest LSN that is not committed (open transaction). The easiest way to get that will be very much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a newer version of DB2 (10.1 or higher, although I want to say a few of these are in 9.7). You have the Monitor [views](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0061229.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-3-9&lang=en) and [functions](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0053963.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-3-10&lang=en).

The [MON_CURRENT_SQL view](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056511.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-3-9-2) and the [MON_GET_ACTIVITY table function](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0060766.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-3-10-10&lang=en) look like they could possibly be what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but, i cannot find in these views the open transaction list and/or transaction id.

Comment: @Dror those were just recommendations. If you take a peek at the views and functions lists that I linked to, you may find the exact one you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your recommendations but i could not find what i was looking for. Basically i need the oldest LSN that is not committed (open transaction). The easiest way to get that will be very much appreciated :-)

Comment: Anybody? i still could not find a way to get the list of open transactions or something else that will help me :-(

Comment: If it runs server side only, perhaps you need to use something like PuTTY to remote to the server to run it.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I'm doing it programmatically. And since my software is running on a different machine, I need a way to get this info from client side. I would really appreciate any idea!

Comment: @Dror - is this for a report? Why would you need the list of uncommitted transactions on a client? Perhaps you would be better off having db2pd run on the server and a report sent out?

Comment: Thanks Chris, but its not for reporting. My software basically needs the oldest not committed LSN. i could have got it if i had the list of open transactions. Maybe there is a way to get the oldest not committed LSN, or oldest open transaction?

Comment: Hi, is there a way to get the corresponded TID or LSN/LRI from the APPL_ID_OLDEST_XACT ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select OLDEST_TX_LSN 
from table(sysproc.MON_GET_TRANSACTION_LOG(-1))
```